# Road data merge weather condition

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, symbology, geometry

I have a shapefile that shows fog, wind and precipitation values ​​between 1 and 5. Additionally, this file consists of grids. My goal is to segment the OSM road data that fall into these grids in this way. My aim is to create a map like the image I gave. How can I do this with Python, PostGIS and QGIS?

What I've done so far:

- Tried nested function with rule-based symbology
- When I did this, I could only color the grids, so I could not achieve my goal.
- I tried to create two separate tables with PostGIS. As path and risk values. However, I could not reach the correct conclusion because there are multiple risk names and risk values.

  SELECT osm_id, grid_id, ST_Intersection(osm_geom, grid_geom) as intersection_geom
  FROM osm_paths, grids
  WHERE ST_Intersects(osm_geom, grid_geom);

I also wonder if the answer to my question can be tried with Trajectools v2

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site, using a Focused question/Best answer model.  Questions should state what you have attempted, and where you are stuck. Please [Edit] your Question to provide details about how you have integrated PostgreSQL/PostGIS into your QGIS project,  what PyQGIS code you have, and what problem your are encountering.

Comment: Intersect the roads by the grid, as result you will have sets of roads. Then join them with the grids values for fog, wind, etc.

Comment: adding more tools only adds complexity. This should be doable in QGIS following what Gregorz said :)